# "Failed to convert parameter value from int64 to int32"

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm inserting few values into a SQL Server table. When I'm getting the values from the front end they are strings. So I need to convert them to `int` first, before I can insert them into the table.

I'm using this code:

```
Int64 x = Convert.ToInt64(some string value);
```

This `x` I want to insert into the table, into a column of type `numeric(18,0)`.

When doing this conversion, I get an error

> *Failed to convert parameter value from int64 to int32*

while my all the values are just like 1000 around.

Answer (score 4):

Use `int x = Convert.ToInt32(some string value)` and it should work.

Your db expects a value of type `Int32`. SQL server won't implicitly convert a 64-bit number to a 32-bit number because of the potential loss of information.

Comment: i used your code with few changes "int x = (int)Convert.ToInt64(some string value)"   and now its working fine. anyway thank you so much for your post. regards- ammy

Comment: @user1766397 Glad I could help. Please accept the answer by activating the checkmark on the left if the answer was helpful. And welcome to stackoverflow!

Answer (score 2):

An `Int64` ranges from `−9,223,372,036,854,775,808` to `9,223,372,036,854,775,807`, which as you can see is 19 characters long (excluding the commas) so it wouldn't fit in you numeric range of 18.  If you really want to use an `Int64` for small numbers like 1000, you should amend your column to the datatype `bigint`.

Answer (score 0):

For System.Int64 (long) in sql server side you must use bigint data type. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187745.aspx